# XSLT document for-each and image syntax

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xhtml

I am trying to use the code below to select all values of notableWork, so for each notableWork get its value and get the next one etc. It is sort of working as two "Notable Work:" are appearing just not the values of notable work.

```
<xsl:for-each select="notableWork">

<p>

Notable Work: <xsl:value-of select="notableWork" />

</p>

</xsl:for-each>
```

The other issue I am having is with images. I have been messing around with the img tag trying variations of it, below is just what I have ended up with. I have an element called imaged which contains a value of image2.jpg, image4.jpg etc. I cannot seem to get it to work :P Just wondering what the correct syntax is, using google I found variations of  so really not sure.

```
<img src="<xsl:value-of select="image" />" />
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:for-each select="notableWork">
  <p>
  Notable Work: <xsl:value-of select="notableWork" />
  </p>
</xsl:for-each>
```

can never work unless you have a nesting like notableWork/notableWork. You already selected `notableWork` so you cant select it again. So you should work with the node, the current node. Which is XSLT: `.`, `current()` or XPath: `self::node()`. All 3 can be used for the same effect.

```
Notable Work: <xsl:value-of select="." />
```

or

```
Notable Work: <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
```

To set the attribute of a image tag you can use

```
<img>
  <xsl:attribute name="src">
    <xsl:value-of select="images" />
  </xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

or

```
<img src="{image}"/>
```

Comment: Wouldnt happen to know what is it for href would you? I tried to use: Website: <a href="{website}" /> - This is also in a for-each.

Comment: <a href="{website}" /> should work, maybe you selected another node then you're expecting

Comment: yeh figured it out eventually, was just a matter of syntax, thanks again :)